# div to behave like textarea when selecting text

Tags: jquery, html, select, textarea

In textarea, normally if you select the text and highlight by dragging it, it only highlights the texts within the textarea.

How do you apply the same traits to div?

I want to know the way to only highlight the texts within the div that has been selected.

Comment: What do you mean by "div that has been selected"?

Comment: What about this? [Making content editable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content) 'All you have to do is set the contenteditable attribute on nearly any HTML element to make it editable.'